# Can't Connect to Logstash Server from Client using Filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, elk

i'm trying to start filebeat and send the output to ELK server, but getting the following error message when run command `/usr/share/filebeat/bin/filebeat -e -c /etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml`

error message:

```
2021-10-18T11:46:18.575Z        ERROR   [logstash]      logstash/async.go:280   Failed to publish events caused by: write tcp 172.31.20.157:48724->MyPublicIP:5044: write: connection reset by peer
2021-10-18T11:46:18.575Z        INFO    [publisher]     pipeline/retry.go:219   retryer: send unwait signal to consumer
2021-10-18T11:46:18.575Z        INFO    [publisher]     pipeline/retry.go:223     done
2021-10-18T11:46:20.215Z        ERROR   [publisher_pipeline_output]     pipeline/output.go:180  failed to publish events: write tcp 172.31.20.157:48724->MyPublicIP:5044: write: connection reset by peer
2021-10-18T11:46:20.215Z        INFO    [publisher_pipeline_output]     pipeline/output.go:143  Connecting to backoff(async(tcp://MyPublicIP:5044))
2021-10-18T11:46:20.215Z        INFO    [publisher]     pipeline/retry.go:219   retryer: send unwait signal to consumer
2021-10-18T11:46:20.215Z        INFO    [publisher]     pipeline/retry.go:223     done
2021-10-18T11:46:20.216Z        INFO    [publisher_pipeline_output]     pipeline/output.go:151  Connection to backoff(async(tcp://MyPublicIP:5044)) established
2021-10-18T11:46:20.273Z        ERROR   [logstash]      logstash/async.go:280   Failed to publish events caused by: write tcp 172.31.20.157:48726->MyPublicIP:5044: write: connection reset by peer
```

here is the filbeat.yml config

```
# ------------------------------ Logstash Output -------------------------------
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
        hosts: ["MyPublicIP:5044"]
```

and here is the logstash-sample.conf in the ELK server

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    type => "logs"
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
  }
  file {
    path => "/var/log/*.log"
    type => "syslog"
  }
  file {
    path => "/tmp/logstash.txt"

  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["MyPublicIP:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    #user => "elastic"
    #password => "changeme"
  }
}
```

i'm able to telnet the logstash from filbeat client server

```
[root@ip-172-x-x-x-system]# telnet MyPublicIP 5044
Trying MyPublicIP ...
Connected to MyPublicIP .
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: Your logstash beats input is using ssl, but your filebeat output does not have ssl configured. Configure SSL in the output according to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuring-ssl-logstash.html) to see if the errors still persists.